# Compiling PHP error: "make: *** [libs/libphp5.bundle] Error 1"

Tags: php, imap

I want to make a program in php that can send and receive emails through a gmail address. I was originally using a XAMPP server on my PPC Mac running OS X 10.4 Tiger, but it didn't have the ssl support that I needed. Because of this, I tried to set up an (updated) Apache server because the one shipped with my mac was outdated. By compiling from the source, I have installed an Apache server (2.2), the imap extension for php, and the openssl extension for php. (Though I don't know if that's needed.)

I ran the configure command like this:

> ./configure --with-imap=/usr/local/imap-2007f/ --enable-sockets --with-imap-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-kerberos

I then did the "make" command as was instructed in the INSTALL file in php.3.5.12 directory. This resulted in:

> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [libs/libphp5.bundle] Error 1

I have researched this error, and seems to result from a lot of different things that don't appear related to my project. For one, they all seem to use (or try to use) MySQl. For my purposes, I don't need that. I am just looking for a way to return to programming so that I can finish my program.

Thanks for any and all help!

Edit: Here is the full error message:

```
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin8/4.0.1/ld: Undefined symbols:  
_iconv  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
make: *** [libs/libphp5.bundle] Error 1
```

Comment: That is only an indication that an error happened earlier; it doesn't say anything at all about what the error was.  Can you provide more details?

Comment: Thanks, tell me if that's better.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem too, and I've solved it, with lots of efforts. I was installing `PHP5.5.12` on `OS X 10.9.2`.

The default Makefile will find `libiconv.2.dylib` under `/usr/lib/` with statement

`19 MH_BUNDLE_FLAGS = -bundle -bundle_loader /usr/sbin/httpd -L/usr/lib -laprutil-1 -lldap -llber -llber -lexpat -liconv -lsqlite3 -lldap -llber -llber -L/usr/lib -lapr-1 -lpthread`

But there's no proper libiconv with right architecture under `/usr/lib/` in `OS X` for PHP. I guess the default `libiconv.2.dylib` under that folder is 32bits architecture supported.

So, we know what the problem exactly is now. We have different ways to solve this.

1. **(not recommended)** Install newest libiconv( available from gnu-libiconv(https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/#downloading)) with configuration `--prefix=/usr`

   but this way may derive other harder problems. Because the OS X need the original `libiconv.2.dylib`. After I changed it, many applications including QQ, TeamViewer and such x86 supported application couldn't be opened anymore. They crashed instantly. If you really get into this situation, don't worry, it could be solved. You can check my gist.github.com/Yougmark. Anyway, php could be installed.
2. **(recommended)** Install newest libiconv( available from [gnu-libiconv]) with configuration `--prefix=/usr/local`

   then modify the Makefile before `$make` to statement below:

   `19 MH_BUNDLE_FLAGS = -bundle -bundle_loader /usr/sbin/httpd -L/usr/local/lib -laprutil-1 -lldap -llber -llber -lexpat -liconv -lsqlite3 -lldap -llber -llber -L/usr/local/lib -lapr-1 -lpthread`

   pay attention to two position of **`-L/usr/lib`**, change them to **`-L/usr/local/lib`**

Now, make and install, and enjoy with new PHP!  **: )** For any details you can refer to my [gist](https://gist.github.com/Yougmark/5128e4e45c4da57fdbc6).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `iconv` library isn't installed.  Unless you require it you could try disabling the support using `--without-iconv` configure option.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked, but then I got a different error. Working on that now.  
  
`/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin8/4.0.1/ld: Undefined symbols:  
_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size  
_EVP_CIPHER_block_size  
_EVP_CIPHER_iv_length  
_EVP_CIPHER_key_length  
_EVP_MD_size  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1`

Comment: @user1376127 can you post your `configure` options?

Answer (score 0):

Note that I had to run "make clean" after changing my Makefile to get it working